# Картинка прогружается только на половину экрана

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, bootstrap

При загрузке, страница прогружается только на половину:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не понимаю в чем дело. Использую `Angular 2` + `AdminLTE`. Причем, если слить `index.html` и `app.component.html` в один файл, то все хорошо.

**`index.html`**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>AdminLTE 2 | Dashboard</title>
    <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
    <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.6 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/admin-lte/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Ionicons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
    <!-- Theme style -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/admin-lte/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">
    <!-- AdminLTE Skins. Choose a skin from the css/skins
         folder instead of downloading all of them to reduce the load. -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/admin-lte/dist/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css">
    <!-- iCheck -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/iCheck/flat/blue.css">
    <!-- Morris chart -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/morris/morris.css">
    <!-- jvectormap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.css">
    <!-- Date Picker -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/datepicker/datepicker3.css">
    <!-- Daterange picker -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css">
    <!-- bootstrap wysihtml5 - text editor -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.min.css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>


  </head>

  <body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <my-app>Загрузка...</my-app>
    </div>
    <!-- ./wrapper -->

    <!-- jQuery 2.2.3 -->
    <script src="node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
    <!-- jQuery UI 1.11.4 -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Resolve conflict in jQuery UI tooltip with Bootstrap tooltip -->
    <script>
        $.widget.bridge('uibutton', $.ui.button);
    </script>
    <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.6 -->
    <script src="node_modules/admin-lte/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Morris.js charts -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/morris/morris.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Sparkline -->
    <script src="node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js"></script>
    <!-- jvectormap -->
    <script src="node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js"></script>
    <!-- jQuery Knob Chart -->
    <script src="node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/knob/jquery.knob.js"></script>
    <!-- daterangepicker -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.2/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
    <!-- datepicker -->
    <script src="node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap WYSIHTML5 -->
    <script src="node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.all.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Slimscroll -->
    <script src="node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/slimScroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
    <!-- FastClick -->
    <script src="node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/fastclick/fastclick.js"></script>
    <!-- AdminLTE App -->
    <script src="node_modules/admin-lte/dist/js/app.min.js"></script>
    <!-- AdminLTE dashboard demo (This is only for demo purposes) -->
    <script src="node_modules/admin-lte/dist/js/pages/dashboard.js"></script>
    <!-- AdminLTE for demo purposes -->
    <script src="node_modules/admin-lte/dist/js/demo.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**`app.component.html`**

```
<header class="main-header">
    <!-- Logo -->
    <a href="/" class="logo">
        <!-- mini logo for sidebar mini 50x50 pixels -->
        <span class="logo-mini"><b>A</b>LT</span>
        <!-- logo for regular state and mobile devices -->
        <span class="logo-lg"><b>Natalie</b>Statistics</span>
    </a>
    <!-- Header Navbar: style can be found in header.less -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top">
        <!-- Sidebar toggle button-->
        <a href="#" class="sidebar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" role="button">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        </a>

        <div class="navbar-custom-menu">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
<!-- Left side column. contains the logo and sidebar -->
<aside class="main-sidebar">
    <!-- sidebar: style can be found in sidebar.less -->
    <section class="sidebar">

        <!-- search form -->
        <form action="#" method="get" class="sidebar-form">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" name="q" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button type="submit" name="search" id="search-btn" class="btn btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                            </button>
                          </span>
            </div>
        </form>

        <!-- /.search form -->
        <!-- sidebar menu: : style can be found in sidebar.less -->
        <ul class="sidebar-menu">
            <li class="header">Список опций</li>


            <li class="treeview">
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-circle-o text-aqua"></i>
                    <span>Отчеты</span>
                    <span class="pull-right-container">
                              <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                            </span>
                </a>
                <ul class="treeview-menu">
                    <li><a href="/report/statistic"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Статистика</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/report/dispatch"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Рассылка</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </section>
    <!-- /.sidebar -->
</aside>

<!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
<div class="content-wrapper">

    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <section class="content-header">
        Заголовок
    </section>

    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">
        Контент
    </section>
    <!-- /.content -->

</div>


<!-- /.content-wrapper -->
<footer class="main-footer">
    Футер
</footer>


<!-- Add the sidebar's background. This div must be placed
     immediately after the control sidebar -->
<div class="control-sidebar-bg"></div>
```

**`app.component.ts`**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

Comment: так может со стилями что-то не то? в css что задано для блока?

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего надо указать стили для компонента, там где  @Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html',
      styleUrls:['app/app.component.css'- путь к вашему файлу]
}).